# React Native erro "Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined onPress

Tags: react, react-native

Eu estou com um problema no código eu estou tentando acessar uma tela pressionando um botão, até ai tudo bem mas o problema é que eu estou tentando passar uma props para o `onPress`, mas está acontecendo esse erro:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined onPress C:/Users/21/projetoTeste/screens/home.js:57 54 | 55 | return( 56 |
> 57 | <TouchableOpacity style={this.styles.bntStyle} onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate(this.props.screen)}> | ^ 58 | {this.props.titulo} 59 | {this.props.subTitulo} 60 | <Image style={this.styles.img} source={require('./imagens/cadeado.png')}/>

Basicamente eu criei um classe chamada `Bnt` que é um botão que recebe várias props e uma delas é a props `screen` que recebe justamente para qual tela irá passando para o `onPress` lá na classe `Bnt` do código acima.

Abaixo é a classe sendo usada:

```html
<Btn titulo='Módulo 1:' subTitulo='Fundamentos' left ='50' screen = 'modulo1'/>
                            
<Btn titulo='Módulo 2:' subTitulo='Hardware' screen = 'modulo2'/>

<Btn titulo='Módulo 3:' subTitulo='Software' screen = 'modulo3'/>

<Btn titulo='Módulo 4:' subTitulo='Internet' screen = 'modulo4'/>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Answer (score 0):

O que ocorre é que a props "navigation" vai existir apenas para as telas que você informou na hora de criar as suas rotas. Se você por exemplo tiver uma tela "home" no seu arquivo de rotas, e ela tiver um componente para fazer os botões, os componentes de botões não herdam o navigation.

Para que elas possam usar o "navigation", uma das soluções é passar ela como props para o seu componente.

```
<Btn titulo='Módulo 1:' subTitulo='Fundamentos' left ='50' screen = 'modulo1' navigation = {this.props.navigation}/>
```

Fazendo isso, o seu componente Btn vai conseguir fazer a navegação para a tela que você informou na props "screen".

```
 <TouchableOpacity style={this.styles.bntStyle} onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate(this.props.screen)}>
 <Image style={this.styles.img} source={require('./imagens/cadeado.png')}/>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Obrigado Irmão funcionou aqui, você é 10.